# AngularJs 1.7 Data inside es6 component not available on template file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I just create the project AngularJs 1.7 and webpack 4 with ES6 class on component and module setup.

this is my app main module.

```
// Core Styles
import './styles/main.scss';

// Core Angular
import angular from 'angular';

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import CommonModule from './modules/common/common.module';
import PackagesModule from './modules/packages/packages.module';
import PackagesService from "./services/packages.service";

// These all export the module name
// import ngAnimateModuleName from 'angular-animate';

const dependencies = [
    // ngAnimateModuleName
    CommonModule.name,
    PackagesModule.name
];

angular.module('app', dependencies)
    .component('appComponent', AppComponent)
    .service('PackagesService', ['$http', PackagesService]);
```

this is my js component file.

```
import './app.component.scss';

export const AppComponent = {
    template: require('./app.component.html'),
    controller: [
        'PackagesService',
        class AppController {
            constructor (PackagesService) {
                this.test = 11;
            }
    }]
};
```

But seems like `test` variable is not available inside the template file.

```
<header-component></header-component>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="packages-name-box">
                <h1 class="homepage-title">Packages Name {{ test }}</h1>
                <packages-list-group pages-data="pagesPackageData"></packages-list-group>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

And this is HTML LOADER inside webpack.confing

```
{
    // HTML LOADER
    // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
    // Allow loading html through js
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'raw-loader'
}
```

Am i missing something why `this.test` is not display anything inside the template?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: use `controllerAs` property on your component definition and use that controller alias prop on page before your variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using ControllerAs syntax, you should assign the value to the $scope variable,

```
$scope.test = 11;
```

you need to inject $scope as

```
 'PackagesService','$scope',
        class AppController {
            constructor (PackagesService,$scope) {
                 $scope.test = 11;
            }
```

Comment: But $scope is undefined, only injected service is available.

Comment: @VarisDarasirikul inject it, or use controlleras syntax

Comment: But i try to set `this.scope = $scope;` and then when i call `this.scope.apply()` to update view why it says `.apply()` not a function?

Comment: it should be $scope.$apply();

Comment: forget it i forgot that it have to be `$apply()`

Answer (score 0):

On angularjs components, all variables declared with `this` can be acessed by the object $ctrl on the scope. You should use:

```
<h1 class="homepage-title">Packages Name {{ $ctrl.test }}</h1>
```

you can change the object name to whatever you want on `controllerAs` like this: (but it's `$ctrl` by default)

```
export const AppComponent = {
template: require('./app.component.html'),
controllerAs: 'vm',
controller: [
    'PackagesService',
    class AppController {
        constructor (PackagesService) {
            this.test = 11;
        }
}]
};
```

see angularjs component document: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: Best pratices: using $scope is not recommended, you should use $ctrl